# How to replicate Postman POST request using java

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

I am trying to replicate Postman POST type request in java. I am sending a file with raw product data to datahub and processing it. According to requirement it should be replicated using a cronjob.

Any one help please.

Comment: You need to add Postman configuration (headers, form type) for correct answer. Your question  is related with java rather than hybris.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring framework you can use spring rest client for consuming RESTful service. Good sample is [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/).

If you are using java, you can use JAX-RS library, sample application [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jersey-jax-rs-client).

Answer (score -1):

There should be a generated Impex file following a publication from DataHub which will be imported via cronjob.